# how fill select by dynamic id in javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I want to select an element, but the id of each element is dynamic and the id is stored in the `chemicalsNum` variable. I have written this code but it doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById(`${chemicalsNum}`).value;
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using `document.getElementById(chemicalsNum).value;`?

Comment: What is the problem with your code

Comment: if an ID attribute is dynamic try to get it via getElementsByTagName instead

Comment: @Raphael, then how will he distinguish desired tag from the group fo tags.

Comment: Yeah you will need to supply a JSfiddle @Farzin. Does this not work because the element doesn't exist or because the values isn't what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing here jQuery-syntax and DOM-syntax which obviously is not working.
You can either use this [DOM syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```
document.getElementById(chemicalsNum).value;
```

or this for [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-item-using-class-or-id/) (or any other library that is supporting that syntax):

```
$('#' + chemicalsNum).val()
```

Depending on the element you've to replace `val()` by another function perhaps. The val-function for jquery is described [here](https://api.jquery.com/val/).